# Google Authentication not giving access to YouTube API [images]?

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm currently working on a YouTube app that will allow users to Log In with their Google Accounts so they can subscribe to other YouTube channels and Like/Dislike videos. However Google doesn't seem to give me access to their YouTube channels even though that option is turned on.

As you can see here the YouTube API is turned on
[image]

However when the user is presented to use my App with his account it doesn't ask the user for access to the YouTube channel.

[image]

When you look at other applications you can see that they ask for permission for their channel.

[image]

Has anyone experienced something similar or does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong :( ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of your app not passing the proper scope when doing the oAuth authentication. In your code, where your client sets the oAuth scopes, make sure that this is one of the ones you're passing:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube